# VBA Lookup compare two cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if anyone could help.
Just trying to compare values from Cell D to Cell B and Return the value in Cell C (Blue box from the screenshot).
Need to do this lookup to all cell in Column D.
Thanks!

[image]

Haven't tried anything yet as I couldn't find any sample.

Comment: VLOOKUP function can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like This ?

```
Sub lookup()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet


Range("E2").Select
    Range("E2").Formula = "=Xlookup(D2,B:B,C:C)"
    Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


End Sub
```

[image]